# Unable to pass custom (struct) types as an argument in C# functions?

Tags: c#, methods, struct

I am trying to pass custom `struct` values to a `public static` method in C# but it is giving

> Error 1 Inconsistent Accessibility

My `main` method code :

```
            Console.WriteLine("Distance 1");
            Console.Write("Enter feet : ");
            int feet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Inches : ");
            float inches = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            P4_Distance distance1 = new P4_Distance(feet, inches);

            Console.WriteLine("Distance 2");
            Console.Write("Enter feet : ");
            feet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Inches : ");
            inches = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            P4_Distance distance2 = new P4_Distance(feet, inches);

            P4_Compare_distances(distance1, distance2);
```

and my `struct` is simply :

```
struct P4_Distance
        {
            public int feet { get; set; }
            public float inches { get; set; }
            public float totalInches { get; set; }

            public P4_Distance(int Feet,float Inches)
            {
                feet = Feet;
                inches = Inches;
                totalInches = inches + (feet * 12);
            }

        }
```

the method that is giving error is :

```
public static void P4_Compare_distances(P4_Distance distance1, P4_Distance distance2)
        {
            if (distance1.totalInches > distance2.totalInches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Distance 1 > Distance 2");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Distance 2 > Distance 1");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Change your struct declaration to `public struct P4_Distance`, or remove `public` from `P4_Compare_distances`. The error is because your method is usable from areas of the program that can't necessarily access the types of the parameters specified.

Comment: It worked ! thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using a `struct` instead of a `class`? Also if you really do need to use a struct you really really should make it Immutable (Read-Only) by making the `set` in to `private set` on the 3 properties. It is very, very, easy to introduce bugs in to your code by having mutable structs.

Comment: Yes thank you @ScottChamberlain for your advice I will work on it , and for struct no reason , I am new to C# and and was just solving a struct chapter problem which said so.

Answer (score 2):

declare the struct as public:

```
public struct P4_Distance
{
 ...
}
```

Without the public the structure has protected accessibility. You cannot expose a protected structure as a public element somewhere - that would defeat the purpose of the protected accessibility.

By making the the struct public you make the accessibility consistent.